# Sending camera data with Wi-Fi from SmartEyeGlass to host device

Tags: android, sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I have an application that scans QR code with SmartEyeGlass.But It goes so slow.I belive thats because the app sending camera data from glass to host device with bluetooth. Is there any way to speed this process up? For instance can I use Wi-Fi instead of bluetooth to speed up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can actually switch the SmartEyeglass in to High Power Mode which will send the images over wifi. To activate High Power Mode you can run this command:

```
utils.setPowerMode(Intents.POWER_MODE_HIGH);
```

You can read more about this function here:
https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/guides/settings/

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks Robert. Sometimes the connection fails but I belive it is about the smart device that I use. Except that It works fine.@Robert - Sony

Comment: Hey Ozan, I am currently trying to get my QR reader working with the SonySmartGlass, can you maybe have a look at it its always crashing when I look at the qr code ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961527/cordova-plugin-sony-smarteyeglass